# RPM Build fails on file I didn't edit

Tags: centos, centos7, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm on CentOS 7 trying to rebuild a kernel from source, only having edited the buildid value in the kernel.spec file. When I try to build, It goes on fine for a while and then fails.

From what I understand in the error log, it's failing due to errors in a file I never touched.

The build command I used was

rpmbuild  -bb --without debug   --without debuginfo --target=`uname -m` kernel.spec 2> build-err.log | tee build-out.log

The error log looks like this.

```
In file included from bench/futex-hash.c:17:0:
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_wait':
bench/futex.h:36:10: error: 'SYS_futex' undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:45:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_WAIT, val, timeout, NULL, 0, opflags);
         ^
bench/futex.h:36:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:45:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_WAIT, val, timeout, NULL, 0, opflags);
         ^
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_wake':
bench/futex.h:36:10: error: 'SYS_futex' undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:55:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_WAKE, nr_wake, NULL, NULL, 0, opflags);
         ^
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_lock_pi':
bench/futex.h:36:10: error: 'SYS_futex' undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:66:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, detect, timeout, NULL, 0, opflags);
         ^
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_unlock_pi':
bench/futex.h:36:10: error: 'SYS_futex' undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:75:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_UNLOCK_PI, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, opflags);
         ^
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_cmp_requeue':
bench/futex.h:36:10: error: 'SYS_futex' undeclared (first use in this function)
  syscall(SYS_futex, uaddr, op | opflags, val, timeout, uaddr2, val3)
          ^
bench/futex.h:87:9: note: in expansion of macro 'futex'
  return futex(uaddr, FUTEX_CMP_REQUEUE, nr_wake, nr_requeue, uaddr2,
         ^
bench/futex.h: In function 'futex_wait':
bench/futex.h:46:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
mv: cannot stat 'bench/.futex-hash.o.tmp': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [bench/futex-hash.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [bench] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [perf-in.o] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GPuhpL (%build)
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GPuhpL (%build)
```

Comment: This sounds like a generic kernel building problem; you should check first that you can build the source snapshot without your mods.